# How can I invoke a function at special position after receiving outer special message in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Let us look at a segment of a code: csharp

```
public void TestMethod(){
  //do something
  string a = await WaitingObj.Read();
  //continue to do something
}
```

And we have a message queue, which is receiving messages all the time. When it finds the message is what the `TestMethod()` needs, it will pass this message to `WaitingObj.Read()` which will return the value and pass the value to the `string a`.

However, We know we cannot invoke `Read()` twice (in the `TestMethod()` to pass the value and when the queue receives new messages to judge whether the message is the `TestMethod()` needs).

So, How can I solve this problem with Await/Async or design the programs.

The message queue in the problem is just a simple queue structure in basic data structure.

The function of WaitingObj.Read() is just indicating when the data is ready for passing to `string a` and `string a` can directly use it can continue carrying the rest of codes.

Comment: You can't change code but need a solution?

Comment: That code doesn't compile. You can only use `await` in an `async` method. There's no queue or message in the question. It's unclear what `message queue` even means here.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the prolbem correctly, but why is `while (true) { if (WaitingObj.IsReady) await TestMethod(); else await Task.Delay(1) };` not an option?

Comment: What message queue are you using? An actual queue like RabbitMQ? Those have async methods already. An in-memory container you call a queue? In that case you need to post its code. In .NET you can use Channel as an asynchronous publisher/subscriber queue or ConcurrentQueue/BlockingCollection as *blocking* queues

Comment: @MichaelMao. Sorry, I wonder if I can just solve it by designing WaitingObj.Read(). Of course we can change the other code.

Comment: @EpicMo solve *what*? What is that `WaitingObj`? What is `Read()`? We can't guess what those methods do. If you used Channel, you could write eg `await foreach(var msg in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())` to asynchronously read all incoming messages indefinitely. Or you could use `await channel.Reader.ReadAsync()` in a loop.

Comment: `is just a simple queue structure in basic data structure.` that's definitely not a .NET [Queue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0). If you want to receive messages asynchronously you can't use a simple Queue<T> or even a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. That's handled by [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels) and at a higher level [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Do some lock in ```WaitingObj.Read();```?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. Maybe I choose the simple structure in the project and cannot implement this function easily ... I am trying to change the queue.

Comment: _"When it finds the message is what the TestMethod() needs"_ - how would it do that?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thank you, I wonder if I can implementing a publisher/subscriber pattern without using While(true) .

Comment: I already answered that. Yes, you can, with a Channel. You'll be able to write `await foreach(var msg in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync()){ ....}`. You should probably explain the *actual* problem, not how you tried to solve it. You can use a Channel as a queue, or an ActionBlock to run a "worker" task that processes messages. You don't have to implement an async queue or even an async pipeline yourself

Comment: @Fildor Such as a special string like "hello" and passes it to the `string a`

Comment: WHat happens to the messages that are _not_ special? Are they dropped? Can the message queue be consumed by other `Read()` calls , too?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, the other messages will be ignored.

Comment: @EpicMo I repeat, we can't guess how `WaitingObj` works. You can't just add `await` to a synchronous method to make it asynchronous. You can't peek messages in a queue unless that queue already supports this. `Queue<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue` have a `TryPeek` method

Comment: `Yes, the other messages will be ignored` that's not what Fildor asked - will the other messages be *discarded*? Or left in the queue for some other method to process? If you can discard unwanted messages there's no need to call `Read` twice - just read every message and ignore those you don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through your post and all the comments, I noticed in particular  where you said:

> I wonder if I can just solve it by designing WaitingObj.Read()....

Let's entertain that thought by designing a `Queue` that provides some basic observability by implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` and provides these features:

- A `ReadAsync` method to await a "special" message that matches a specified predicate.
- A `SelfTest` method that enqueues one message per second from a list of 10 messages.

An instance of `var WaitingObj = new DesignedObservableQueue()` can then be exercised in a console app to see **whether or not** this would satisfy your design specs.

---

**Designed Queue (a.k.a. "WaitingObj")**

```
class DesignedObservableQueue : Queue<MockMessage>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public new void Enqueue(MockMessage message)
    {
        base.Enqueue(message);
        CollectionChanged?
            .Invoke(
                this,
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, 
                    message));
    }
    public new MockMessage Dequeue()
    {
        var message = base.Dequeue();
        CollectionChanged?
            .Invoke(
                this,
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                    NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, 
                    message));
        return message;
    }
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;
```

Provide a way to detect that a special message has been enqueued.

```
    public async Task ReadAsync(Predicate<MockMessage> condition)
    {
        var awaiter = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        try
        {
            CollectionChanged += localOnCollectionChanged;
            await awaiter.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            awaiter.Release();
            CollectionChanged -= localOnCollectionChanged;
        }

        void localOnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    var message = e.NewItems!.Cast<MockMessage>().First();
                    if(condition(message))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"MATCH: {message.Message}");
                        awaiter.Release();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"NO MATCH: {message.Message}");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Mock a queue that "is receiving messages all the time" by self-enqueuing at one-second intervals.

```
    public async Task SelfTest(CancellationToken token)
    {
        foreach (
            var message in new[]
            {
                "occasion",
                "twin",
                "intention",
                "arrow",
                "draw",
                "forest",
                "special",
                "please",
                "shell",
                "momentum",
            })
        {
            if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            Enqueue(new MockMessage { Message = message });
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Exercise TestMethod**

Once the `TestMethod` shown in your post is changed to an `async` method, perform this minimal test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Test Runner";
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    var WaitingObj = new DesignedObservableQueue();

    // Local test method is expecting to match
    // the predicate in ~6 seconds so allow 10.
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    stopwatch.Start();

    _ = WaitingObj.SelfTest(cts.Token);
    try
    {
        TestMethod().Wait(cts.Token);
        Console.WriteLine($"PASSED {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FAILED {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    }

    // Local test method
    async Task TestMethod()
    {
        // do something
        await WaitingObj.ReadAsync((message) => message.Message == "special");
        // continue to do something
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: console output]

Where:

```
class MockMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```